# Binding one key to another

Tags: key-bindings

I would like to bind C-h to do exactly the same thing as backspace, no matter
the mode I'm in. So far I bound C-h to delete-backward-char in global-map,
but the results are inconsistent across the modes (it doesn't work well with electric-pair for example, python mode is broken as well).

Answer (score 1):

I use `(define-key key-translation-map [?\C-h] [?\C-?])`, this also works for when backspaces as parts of key sequences, e.g.

```
C-x DEL (translated from C-x C-h) runs the command
backward-kill-sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, for future reference:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-h") (kbd "<backspace>"))
```

Comment: Please consider accepting your own answer. Having an accepted answer can help readers.